# dotnet run, dotnet build vs Start without debugging(Ctrl-F5)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

From *learn.microsoft.com*:

> `dotnet build` - Builds a project and all of its dependencies.
>
> `dotnet run` - Runs source code without any explicit compile or launch commands.

Does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> imply both of the above? To achieve the same results with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, what do I have to run?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`dotnet build`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x) will only build the project without actually running it.

[`dotnet run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore2x) will automatically build the project using `dotnet build` if necessary. You can disable this by running `dotnet run --no-build`.

If you launch a project from within Visual Studio without debugging, then that will be mostly equivalent to `dotnet run`, although it depends a bit on the project type what *exactly* is called. Usually, building inside Visual Studio will invoke MSBuild directly, without relying on `dotnet`.

Comment: One of these subtle difference between ``dotnet run`` and starting from VS: [``dotnet run`` doesn't set SolutionDir](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/22342)